# python datetime.now() not returning updated timestamp from function header of included file

Tags: python, datetime, include

A call to datetime.now() is presently returning the same time as the first time called, even when being called several hours later.

I have the following code. In first.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
import datetime as dt
import fns_print as pr
import fns_time as tm

def main(argv):
  pr.ts_print("STARTED")
  # do a bunch of other stuff that takes 10+ seconds
  pr.ts_print("Finished Download Pass")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```

fns_print.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import fns_time as tme

def ts_print(string, **kwargs):
  """Print timestamped message to stdout and into log file"""
  print("{}: {}".format(tme.strTimeSt(),string),**kwargs)
  return True
```

fns_time.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta ## pip install datetime
from dateutil import tz
PST = tz.tzoffset("PST",-28800) # datetime.tzinfo.FixedOffset(-(8*60),"PST")
UTC = tz.tzutc() # UTC = tz.tzoffset("UTC",0)

def getCurTime(localTime = False):
  """get current time, by default in UTC. if localTime is True, it uses local system time"""
  return datetime.now(tz=UTC) if not localTime else datetime.now(tz=tz.tzlocal())

def strTimeSt(t = datetime.now(tz=UTC), PSTConvert=False):
  """return a string representation of a datetime object. Uses UTC by default
  Can also convert to PST with PSTConvert=True. Never converts to PDT."""
  tf = t if not PSTConvert else t.astimezone(tz=PST)
  return tf.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z (%z)")
```

output of the two calls (one run):

> 2016-12-20 18:45:04 UTC (+0000): STARTED
>   2016-12-20 18:45:04 UTC (+0000): Finished Download Pass

The previous run gave both times as 18:41:28

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default argument value `datetime.now(tz=UTC)` is evaluated once, when the function is defined.  If you want it to be evaluated anew every time the function is called, you need to move it inside the function:

```
def strTimeSt(PSTConvert=False):
  """return a string representation of a datetime object. Uses UTC by default
  Can also convert to PST with PSTConvert=True. Never converts to PDT."""
  t = datetime.now(tz=UTC)
  tf = t if not PSTConvert else t.astimezone(tz=PST)

  return tf.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z (%z)")
```

If you still want to allow passing a datetime in, you could make the default value be None, and then check for None and only call `.now()` if None was passed, like so:

```
def strTimeSt(t=None, PSTConvert=False):
  """return a string representation of a datetime object. Uses UTC by default
  Can also convert to PST with PSTConvert=True. Never converts to PDT."""
  if t is None:
      t = datetime.now(tz=UTC)
  tf = t if not PSTConvert else t.astimezone(tz=PST)
  return tf.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z (%z)")
```